# Registering a Window Class in the Win32API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Despite reading plenty of information throughout the web, along with Petzold's book, *Programming the Windows API*, and damn near copying the exact same methodology out of the book, along with [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context) documentation on how to initialize an OpenGL context, I haven't been able to get an up and running Window Class.

I've tried compiling on both VC++ and MinGW (I'm using Qt Creator), in order to see if this would work. I've tried making my `WNDCLASSEXA` a pointer, as well as allocating it on the stack. No dice for both.

Thus, I'm quite unsure what to do about this. Sometimes the class simply fails to register, where as other times the `HWND` which is returned from `CreateWindowExA`simply doesn't work and returns NULL. After trying to just continue the program, despite these incidents happening, I wind up with an application which fails to draw a window.

The idea is simple: I have a struct which I'm using to simply store all of the data used (`DEVMODEA`, `WNDCLASSEXA`, `HGLRC`, etc).

From there, I use that struct to create a Window, and then pass it back to the function's caller.

All I'm really looking to do is write a simple pong-like game in OpenGL using GLSL/OpenGL 3.3. To do that, I obviously need a context first, but I can't discern whether or not the issue is Qt Creator, Windows, or something else.

So, what could I be doing wrong?

**`GameData` Struct**

```
typedef struct
{
    HGLRC        hrc;
    HDC          hdc;
    HWND         hwnd;
    HINSTANCE    hInstance;
    UINT         numFormats;
    WNDCLASSEXA* winClass;
    DWORD        dwExStyle;
    DWORD        dwStyle;
    RECT         winRect;
    DEVMODEA     screenSettings;

    bool         fullscreen;
    const char*  winClassName;
    int          pixelFormat;
    bool         keys[ 256 ];
    bool         active;
}
GameData;
```

**`initPong()` function**

```
static GameData* initContextAndWindow( void )
{
    GameData* dat = new GameData;

    const int width     = 640;
    const int height    = 480;
    const int bitsPerPixel = 32;

    dat->winRect.left   = ( long )0;
    dat->winRect.right  = ( long )width;
    dat->winRect.top    = ( long )0;
    dat->winRect.bottom = ( long )height;

    dat->fullscreen     = false;

    dat->hInstance              = GetModuleHandleA( NULL );

    dat->winClass = ( WNDCLASSEXA* )calloc( sizeof( WNDCLASSEXA ), 1 );

    if( !dat->winClass )
        MessageBoxA( NULL, "Something wrong!", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION );

    dat->winClass->style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    dat->winClass->lpfnWndProc   = ( WNDPROC ) eventHandler;
    dat->winClass->cbClsExtra    = 1;
    dat->winClass->cbWndExtra    = 1;
    dat->winClass->cbSize        = sizeof( WNDCLASSEXA );
    dat->winClass->hInstance     = dat->hInstance;
    dat->winClass->hIcon         = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_WINLOGO );
    dat->winClass->hCursor       = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
    dat->winClass->hbrBackground = ( HBRUSH ) GetStockObject( WHITE_BRUSH );
    dat->winClass->lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    dat->winClass->lpszClassName = "PongDH";

    if ( !RegisterClassExA( dat->winClass ) )
    {
        MessageBoxA( NULL, "Failed to register class.", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    if ( dat->fullscreen )
    {
        memset( &dat->screenSettings, 0, sizeof( dat->screenSettings ) );

        dat->screenSettings.dmSize          = sizeof( dat->screenSettings );
        dat->screenSettings.dmPelsWidth     = width;
        dat->screenSettings.dmPelsHeight    = height;
        dat->screenSettings.dmBitsPerPel    = bitsPerPixel;
        dat->screenSettings.dmFields        = DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

        if ( ChangeDisplaySettingsA( &dat->screenSettings, CDS_FULLSCREEN ) != DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL )
        {
            dat->fullscreen = false;



            const int continuePlaying = MessageBoxA(
                NULL,
                "Could not implement fullscreen. Please check your drivers. Do you plan to continue?",
                "ERROR",
                MB_YESNO | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION
            );

            if ( continuePlaying == IDYES )
            {
                MessageBoxA( NULL, "Will revert back to fullscreen.", "Notifcation", MB_OK );
                dat->fullscreen = false;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBoxA( NULL, "The program will now close", "Notification", MB_OK );
                exit( 1 );
            }
        }

    }

    if ( dat->fullscreen )
    {
        dat->dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
        dat->dwStyle = WS_POPUP;
        ShowCursor( FALSE );
    }
    else
    {
        dat->dwExStyle  = WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;
        dat->dwStyle    = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
    }

    AdjustWindowRectEx( &dat->winRect, dat->dwStyle, FALSE, dat->dwExStyle );

    dat->hwnd = CreateWindowExA(
                    dat->dwStyle,
                    dat->winClass->lpszClassName,
                    "PongDH",
                    WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
                    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                    dat->winRect.right,
                    dat->winRect.bottom,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    dat->hInstance,
                    NULL
                );


    if ( dat->hwnd == NULL )
    {
        MessageBoxA( NULL, "Failed to create window; exiting program.", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    const int attrList[] =
    {
        WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB  , GL_TRUE,
        WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB  , GL_TRUE,
        WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB   , GL_TRUE,
        WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB      , WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
        WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB      , 32,
        WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB      , 24,
        WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB    , 8,
        0,
    };

    wglChoosePixelFormatARB( dat->hdc, attrList, NULL, 1, &dat->pixelFormat, &dat->numFormats );

    const int contextList[] =
    {
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        0,
    };

    dat->hrc = wglCreateContextAttribsARB( dat->hdc, NULL, contextList );

    if( !wglMakeCurrent( dat->hdc, dat->hrc ) )
    {
        MessageBoxA( NULL, "Error making OpenGL Rendering Context current.", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    ShowWindow( dat->hwnd, SW_SHOW );
    SetForegroundWindow( dat->hwnd );
    SetFocus( dat->hwnd );
    resizeScene( width, height );

    UpdateWindow( dat->hwnd );

    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

    return dat;
}
```

**Update**

Here, I'll post the procedure of what I did:

I first tried setting `cbClsExtra` to 1, whereas before it was 0. Then I set `cbWndExtra` to 1. After that I tried setting the `cbSize` to `sizeof( WNDCLASSEXA )`.

I also tried compiling under both VC++ and MinGW; in VC++, the class simply fails to register, where as in MinGW, the class will register, but it won't actually create the required `hwnd`.

I've also tried editing my code by making `WNDCLASSEXA` (which is `dat->winClass`) a pointer, as opposed to a stack allocated variable.

I've also commenting out my `exit` functions in my `if` checks to see if either the class **doesn't** register, or if the `hwnd` **isn't** created. This yields a segmentation fault upon trying to render the OpenGL context with `wglChoosePixelFormatARB`.

**Update 2**

Here is my WndProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK eventHandler( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    return DefWindowProcA( hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam );
}
```

Comment: How does the code in the question fail?

Comment: Petzold's code works--I've used it. Do we get to guess what goes wrong?

Comment: The `WNDCLASSEXA` either fails to register, or the `dat->hwnd` will not create the window.

Comment: @Holland What do you mean by either? The exact same program behaves differently from one execution to the next?

Comment: @Jonathan I don't doubt it works; I'm just saying for some reason it's not working for me. I'm not asking anyone to guess - rather, I'm trying to see if I'm missing something here. My OpenGL driver is 4.2, and my Windows 7 is up to date. I'm not sure if it's because I'm using Qt Creator, or not, however.

Comment: As an aside, why are you targetting Unicode, but calling ANSI APIs? It would be better to forget all about the ANSI APIs.

Comment: @Holland: Yes, and by not explaining what problem you had, you are making it much more work for people to try and help you. Try and think like a software developer: What did you try? What was the result?

Comment: @David No, not entirely. It depends on what I'm using to compile it. For example: when I switch to VC++, or make the `WNDCLASSEXA` a pointer, it fails to register. Otherwise, it simply won't create the window. I've tried editing the settings for the `WNDCLASSEXA` to see if that would make a difference. Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: Okay, I'm out. Next time, I would recommend spending a little more time defining the problem in very precise terms.

Comment: @Jonathan That's the thing, though: I explained my problem beforehand. Did you read the text all the way through? If I'm missing something, let me know and I'll update it.

Comment: @Holland Unless you can be clear on what is actually failing, and what your question really is, it's hard to say much. "I've tried editing the settings for the WNDCLASSEXA to see if that would make a difference." No idea what that means. Are you really trying to modify the struct definition in the windows header file? Bad idea.

Comment: @Holland: If you think "haven't been able to get an up and running Window class" provides precise details about what failed, you're going to have difficulty as a developer.

Comment: @JonathanWood You've made your point. No need to carry on berating the poor guy!

Comment: Ok, I've updated my text for clarity. That's the best I can explain it, because I don't have any more information to give. If anyone has any questions to ask, though, in particular, I'll try to answer the best I can.

Comment: dat->winClass->cbClsExtra    = 1;
    dat->winClass->cbWndExtra    = 1;
That looks strange, why allocate one byte of memory extra per window and one byte per window class?

Comment: I suggest you cut this down to a minimally reproducible complete program and then post the code. Strip out all the extraneous stuff and just have the program call `RegisterClassEx`, `CreateWindowEx`, `ShowWindow`, `UpdateWindow`, and the message loop.

Comment: A good start would be to **remove all the C style casts**. Make it compile without the casts. The casts just hide bugs.

Comment: @JohnB, I thought if I allocated more memory it might actually produce it, because it may not, for whatever reason, be allocating enough memory.

Comment: After `RegisterClassExA` fails, what is the `GetLastError()`?

Comment: `GetLastError()` simply returns `(NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

> > I haven't been able to get an up and running Window Class.

There really is not a lot to registering and creating a window using the WinAPI.

As an example this simple *test.cpp* file:

```
#define STRICT
#include <windows.h>

long PASCAL WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR lpszCmdParam, int nCmdShow)
{
   static char szClassName[] = "Hello World";
   MSG         msg;
   WNDCLASS    wndclass;

   memset(&wndclass, '\0', sizeof(wndclass));

   if (!hPrevInstance) {
      // define the 'Hello World' window class
      wndclass.style          = CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
      wndclass.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
      wndclass.cbClsExtra     = 0;
      wndclass.cbWndExtra     = 0;
      wndclass.hInstance      = hInstance;
      wndclass.hIcon          = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
      wndclass.hCursor        = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
      wndclass.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH);
      wndclass.lpszMenuName   = 0;
      wndclass.lpszClassName  = szClassName;

      // register the 'Hello World' window class
      RegisterClass (&wndclass);
   }

   // create a new window that is a 'Hello World' window class
   HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                              szClassName,
                              "My Hello World Window",
                              WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                              CW_USEDEFAULT,
                              CW_USEDEFAULT,
                              CW_USEDEFAULT,
                              CW_USEDEFAULT,
                              NULL,
                              NULL,
                              hInstance,
                              NULL);

   ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);

   while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
      TranslateMessage (&msg);
      DispatchMessage (&msg);
   }

   return msg.wParam;
}

long APIENTRY WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message) {
       case WM_DESTROY:
          PostQuitMessage (0);
          return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

can be compiled and linked from the command line:

```
C:\TEMP>cl test.cpp user32.lib gdi32.lib
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:test.exe
test.obj
user32.lib
gdi32.lib
```

and the resulting *test.exe* can be run and it will display a window:

```
C:\TEMP>test.exe
```